# Is there a query to see how far are you from the proofreader badge?

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer, review-badges

So, is there a query to get how far are you from the proofreader badge?

Something like [How many Copy Editor/Strunk & White-qualifying edits have I made?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1397/how-many-copy-editor-strunk-white-qualifying-edits-have-i-made)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably, there might be.  But why would you want to use one when you don't really need it?

You can get the numbers from the site without having to use the data explorer.  You can find this by looking at any suggested edit you have reviewed.  On the page, you'll see counts for how many you have approved and rejected.  Add them up and you'll get your number.

[image: the counts]

Apparently you have made 70 reviews so far.

You can find the list of suggested edits you have reviewed by going to the [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476681/vjo?tab=activity) tab in your profile and select the [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476681/vjo?tab=activity#page_1-filter_reviews) filter.  Click on the `suggested edit` link on a review to see the page.

Comment: That works. Thanks (not need for a query)

Comment: I see you've gotten the badge now, congrats!  :)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to click on your user profile, and then "Select your next badge". If not obtained yet, Proofreader will be in the collection and there is a bar that tracks your progress (e.g. below).

[image]

Comment: This does involve some caching AFAIK, so it might be a little out of date when you just did some reviews.

Comment: Yep, it goes the same for the editing badges in that it takes a short time to update.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I couldn't resist. It's a pain to navigate to the Reviewer Stats. Here's the SEDE query:

```
declare @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 THEN 1 else 0 end) Approvals,
   SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN 1 else 0 end) Rejections,
   (100 - SUM(1)) AS VotesStillNeeded
FROM SuggestedEditVotes
WHERE UserId = @UserId
AND VoteTypeId in (2, 3)
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64662/how-close-am-i-to-the-proofreader-badge